# What's the meaning of 'SYS FAIL' in Tharsis?

Tags: tharsis

On of the modules is having 'SYS FAIL', what's the expected impact of this event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you can't use the module's "ability" until you resolve the event.

During the "Impending Damage" phase, nothing special will occur (no hull damage, or any damage to your characters) if the event isn't resolved.